# Do the residues of $a^n$ modulo $p$ for prime $p$ form a group?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

I was doing a question involving finding the residue of $2^{2015}$ modulo $p$ for prime $p$.

The methodology was to manually compute the sequence of modulos and deduce the order by stopping the moment the sequence repeats.

I thought initially

> But what's the guarantee that the sequence repeats the moment an element has been repeated?

Then it occurred to me that this situation was alarmingly similar to working with the cyclic group of prime order.

So my next guess was that the residues of $a^{n}$ mod $p$ are isomorphic to $C_p$. Is my guess correct? Can this relationship be made more explicit/general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$If $p$ is a prime, then the set $G$ of non-zero residues under multiplication forms a group $G$, of order $p-1$. This group can be shown to be cyclic.

If you take any $a \in G$, its powers will form a subgroup
$$
\langle a \rangle = \{ a^{n} : n \in \Z \}
$$
of $G$. Because $G$ is cyclic, as $a$ ranges over $G$, you will obtain subgroups of each possible order $m$, where $m$ is a divisor of the order $p-1$ of $G$.

As an example, if $p = 7$, then the positive divisors of $6 = 7 - 1$ are $$1, 2, 3, 6.$$
You get subgroups of these orders taking respectively
$$
a = 1, 6, 2, 3. 
$$